# Download PHP in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How do I install php and java in eclipse at the same time,
***NOTE :*** Currently, I'm running java in eclipse.
Thank you!

Comment: Help > Install New Software... choose your main release site, search for PHP in the list

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to install PHP on your system.
   https://www.php.net/
2. If you already have Eclipse, you can download Eclipse PHP development tool. See Update existing Eclipse in:  https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/